# How do I easily rewrite nat.succ (nat.succ 0) as 2?

Tags: lean

Say my proof goal includes `nat.succ (nat.succ 0)`, and I want to quickly rewrite it to say `2`; I can define a whole new theorem:

```
theorem succ_succ_zero_eq_two : nat.succ (nat.succ 0) = 2 := rfl
```

then use that theorem with `rw`, but this seems very clunky. Is there any way to do this in a single line in my proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rw (show nat.succ (nat.succ 0) = 2, by refl),`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution would use the [`change`](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/tactics.html#basic-tactics) tactic:

```
change 2
```

See also [`ac_change`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#convert_to), which can rearrange sums and products as well.